# SpringBoot 2.7.5 - @Value annotation not assigning any values from application.properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.5
While using **@Value** annotation to inject values form **application.properties** file, getting null assignment to variables under **@Configuration** class.

**Example:**

```
@Value("${file.name}")
private String fileName;
```

Here I am getting seeing assignment to variable *fileName*
Ideally it should assign value *'${file.name}'* if key isn't matching. But null assignment means something is breaking in the project (at least I think so, I need experts comments on this).

Same thing is working in another project but not in this particular.

Let me know if my question is not elaborative enough and will try to explain in detail

My question is, why is it working in other project but not in this one. What configurations could go wrong which I need to check. Have gone through multiple stackoverflow solutions and verified all below:

1. application.properties file spell check
2. @Configuration annotation at top of class where @Value is being used
3. key value pair assignment and spell check of all keys
4. no issues with library imports
5. Tried to add **@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")**
6. *import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;*
7. *resources* folder is correctly marked as **'Resources Root'**
8. 

**Temporary Alternative**

```
private Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(VaultCredential.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties"));
props.getProperty("file.name");
```

Comment: Have you verified that you are using the correct [`@Value`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation?

Comment: @Turing85 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

Also added at number 6 in list

Comment: Can you provide a [MRE], e.g. in form of a git repository?

Comment: @Turing85 I can, but sad thing is, its working in other sample project where I tried to replicate it but not in a project which I am working on and it cannot be shared. So I am searching for options which I need to look into like project configuration or spell check or resources folder tagging or anything which I am certainly missing here.

Comment: Run the program with `--trace` to check if your application.properties are loaded.

Comment: Spring boot has default rule to scan packages (package containing the @ SpringBootApplication class ..), but if the name of your class's package doesn't match then you have to add it to a @ComponentScan annotation.

Comment: Check that file.name is defined in your application.properties file.  Then check that you have `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.whatever.appname.*"})` at the top of your your SpringBootApplication class.

Comment: @old_dd
After adding '@ComponentScan' getting below error in editor and suggesting to remove it:

Redundant declaration: '@SpringBootApplication' already applies given '@ComponentScan '

Comment: did you add the basePackages attribute?  SpringBootApplication includes ComponentScan, but the default value, If specific packages are not defined, will cause scanning to occur from the package of the class with this annotation.

Comment: Note sure about solution, but application.properties file was definitely not being loaded at runtime.
So removed '@Value' (which I don't wanted to do) and tried legacy alternative to load properties file and it worked. Still investigating why '@Value' is not loading properties file. @PeterMmm any ideas?

**Temporary solution:**
_private Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(VaultCredential.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties"));
props.getProperty("file.name");_

Comment: An `@Value` like an `@Autowired` cannot be `null`, if that happens a startup exception would occur and the application wouldn't even start. The fact that it is `null` is more an indication that you are creating an instance of the class yourself using `new` and thus it won't be processed by Spring and thus nothing will happen. Also please add the full class and not just a snippet, also show where you are using this/how you are using this and when it is `null`.

Comment: Do you load the properties file in the Application class or do you expect them to be picked up by default?

Comment: Also in the build section in the pom.xml (or the equivalent for gradle) you might need to add them there. Since you have already a project thaty they run it might be easy to compare what they have on those 2 places.

Comment: @Dimitris If we write '@SpringBootApplication', ideally spring should automatically load everything from 'application.properties' file and inject into variables annotated with '@Value'. This is what my understanding is. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Indeed this is the default, but maybe you need to set the property source to use the @Value. There are many ways to do that I check baeldung for example: https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-properties-2/src/main/java/com/baeldung/properties/value/ValuesApp.java Maybe you can try something like that.

Comment: I am using it in my project and I see that we set both propertysource, also in the application class using  return application.sources(Application.class).properties("") and in the pom file. So not sure, which one you need to make it work. That is why I said compare with your other project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies everyone. I was calling a class where was trying to bind `@Value` with properties and calling it in `main()` method of `@SpringBootApplication`.
Totally missed that `main()` method will not load property values until spring application is up and running.

Working solution if some one want to load properties before even running a SpringBoot application -

```
private Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(VaultCredential.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties"));
props.getProperty("file.name");
```

PS - Thanks all for your efforts. Admins can close it down if considered as non-logical question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with below code

```
private String PathForImageGallery;

@Value("${file.name}")
public void PathForImageGallery(String PathForImageGallery) {
    this.PathForImageGallery = PathForImageGallery;
}
```

Comment: Tried this solution, still same result.  
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.base/java.io.File.<init>(File.java:318)`